# How to calculate price from math equation and change price when other values are changed?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to calculate the price of a product from 3 values, the FOB, FI, and Margin, the equation goes like this (FOB / FI) / Margin = price. right now I'm just calling the price from the database but I need it to change dynamically when either of the values are changed. Each product has 3 countries and I need to be able to do it for each country in the same product.

This is how i'm bringing it from the database, not sure how to do the math and set it in here.

```
<el-table
    v-if="model && model.prices"
    :data="model.prices"
    v-loading="loadingPrices || loadingResource"
    class="no-borders">
        <el-table-column>
            <template slot-scope="scope">
                {{ scope.row.country.name }}
            </template>
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column
            width="200"
            label="Precio">
            <template slot-scope="scope">
                <el-input v-model="scope.row.price"
                    class="w-100"
                    controls-position="right"
                    :min="0">
                    <template slot="prepend">{{scope.row.country.currency_symbol}} 
                    </template>
                </el-input>
            </template>
        </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

Comment: You can define a *Laravel Mutator* for that https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator which will auto-save values based on the logic written in Mutator function.